# If and else for Google map click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am setting google markers for my each locations that comes from database, now when user clicks on any icon I am setting that icon active by replacing with active marker image.

But when page is loaded first time I wanna set active icon at specific location this is my code.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
                    {

                     for( var m in $.bgmp.markers )
                        $.bgmp.markers[ m ].setIcon('http://guipme.npmdemo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/marker_img.png');
})
```

for example say I have 4 locations India Pakistan, srilanka and Bangladesh. for every icon I am setting a default img but when user clicks say india i am adding active icon to india. similary I wanna add active icon to bangladesh as default when page loads how can I do this?

Do I need to use if else for click and unclick?

Comment: is there any event called unclick??

Comment: Nobody has ans i know the person who has down voted this please tell me the reason, if you cant do it doesnt means you should down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer as per google developers discussion we can not have click and unclick or its not possible to add if condition for my case say    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load",function(){}) if clicked will wont work. 
I got very interesting stuff from google discussions I will add my inactive icon on page load so there is window load function.

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load",function(){
                        var lastPart = window.location.hash.substr(1);
                        alert("hi"+lastPart+marker['title']);
                        if (marker['title']==lastPart) { 
                     marker.setIcon('../uploads/2015/12/pme_inter_notaires_gcl_location_large.png');    
    }
})
```

This solves my problem by providing me adding default behaviour and changing this default behaviour on click.

Answer (score 0):

A possibile solution could be usin a global var for store the actual active marker

```
var myActiveMarker;
```

In init phase you should show the marker you want active and set this marker to the myActiveMarker var for store

```
 function init() {

  myInitMarker  = new google.maps.Marker({
               .....
  });

  myActiveMarker = myInitMarker;


 }
```

then in your listener simply turn on/off the related markers

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

   myActiveMarker.setIcon('your_icon_not_active');
   marker.setInco('your_icon_active');
   myActiveMarker = marker

})
```